# ValueError while using palette Vega10 in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

Hi I have Anaconda installed on my laptop. Inside it, `matplotlib` version is 1.5.1 and `seaborn` version is 0.7.1. In my jupyter notebook, I was trying to use `seaborn` to do the `countplot`. But when I used `palette = Vega10` inside `seaborn.countplot`, I am getting the following error,

```
ValueError: Vega10 is not a valid palette name
```

But if we use the matplotlib [colormap](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) link, we find that they have listed `Vega10` as one of the many colormaps.

Comment: Try `palette='Vega10'`

Comment: @C S, Actually I used it with single quotes as you describe it. But I am getting this ValueError.

Comment: I tried the other colormaps like 'Accent', 'Dark2', 'Set1', etc. listed under "qualitative" colormaps in the Matplotlib docs, and they worked.  So I guess this is a Seaborn issue.  Maybe it needs to be updated.

Comment: Vega10 was added in matplotlib 2.0.

Comment: @mwaskom So I am using matplotlib version 1.5.1 it seems. How do I update matplotlib inside Anaconda

Comment: the exact same way you update any package `conda update matplotlib`

Comment: @Paul H, thanks. after updating, `palette = Vega10` is working. I wanted a general advice as I am new to python. How often should we update these packages ?

Comment: @user9026 as often as you need the latest features and bugfixes.

Answer (score 1):

> Instead of Vega10 Use the "tab" colormaps : "tab10", "tab20", "tab20b", "tab20c".

```
sb.boxplot(x='Species', y='Sepal Length', data=df, palette='tab10')
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments, the 'Vega10' colormap was added in matplotlib 2.0, updating to that version solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Vega was deprecated and now is tab, just change the code an instead of Vega10 change it to tab10 etc.

https://matplotlib.org/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_2.0.1.html?highlight=vega